# Google App Engine Geo Query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geolocation, google-cloud-datastore, geospatial

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Place 
                      WHERE location >= :1 AND 
                            location <= :2",
                    db.GeoPt(lat=minLat, lon=minLon), 
                    db.GeoPt(lat=maxLat, lon=maxLon) )
```

From what I understand, GAE ignore the long in this case. 
Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: `GeoPt` properties are sorted first by latitude, then by longitude. This query will find entities that fall between the two latitudes, only considering the longitudes if the latitudes are identical.